# RSA signing keys must be PrivateKey instances

Tags: java, jwt, private-key

I Have a problem in making an Jwt for the firebaseCustomToken
RSA signing keys must be PrivateKey instances.
How Can I solve this problem?

```
 Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
header.put("typ", "JWT");
header.put("alg", RS256);

String temp = Jwts.builder()
        .setHeader(headers)
        .setIssuer("client_email_firebaseAdminSDK")
        .setSubject("client_email_firebaseAdminSDK")
        .setAudience("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit")
        .setIssuedAt(cur_time)
        .setExpiration(exp_time)
        .setId(Long.toString(kakaoResult.getUserId()))
        .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor("private_key_of_firebaseAdminSDK".getBytes()), RS256)
        .compact();
```

Comment: [hmacShaKeyFor](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#secretkey-formats) can only be used for HSxxx (HMAC SHAxxx) algorithms. If you want RS256 you need a [proper RSA private key](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#asymmetric-keys)

Comment: Changed to ```signWith( sk, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512 ).compact();``` instead ```SignatureAlgorithm.RS512```and problem solved.